# Three.js how to combine multiple materials with onBeforeCompile

Tags: javascript, three.js

Say i have something like:

```
//some chunks i want to override for functionality FOO
const myNormalChunks = {
   beginnormal_vertex,
   defaultnormal_vertex, 
   normalmap_pars_fragment,
}

//a version of `MeshStandardMaterial` that does FOO instead of default 
class StandardMaterialWithFOO extends THREE.MeshStandardMaterial{
  constructor(params){
    super(params)

    this.onBeforeCompile = shader=> { /*replace chunks by name*/ }
  }
}
```

Now i can use the FOO version of the material. But what if i want to add another version of the `MeshStandardMaterial` that does both FOO and BAR?

```
const BAR_onBeforeCompile = shader => { 
  /* 1. replace another chunk */
  /* 2. add something after beginnormal_vertex */
}


class ShaderMaterialWithFOOandBAR extends StandardMaterialWithFOO {
  constructor(params){
    super(params)
    this.onBeforeCompile = /* ??? */
  }
}
```

1. i'm kinda thinking it is possible through some hacking to pipe these callbacks
2. this wouldn't work though, because there is no `#include <some_chunk>` after the first `onBeforeCompile` processes it, and i have no way of knowing what it got replaced with.

The only thing i can think of tackling this is by having some super global like GLSL code with every possible permutation controlled by `#ifdef`? But i would prefer not to modify the `THREE.ShaderChunk` object globally.

```
someChunk = `
  #ifdef isFOO 
    /* logic */
  #endif

  #ifdef isBAR
    /* logic */
  #endif
`
```

^ this seems somewhat tedious and prone to error though.

Also having something like:

```
const mySuperUberOneSizeFitAllOnBeforeCompile = shader =>{
  if( isBAR ) {...}
  if( isFOO ) {...}
}
```

Does not work because three.js has a caching mechanism that ignores these conditions. Say if I had 10 materials using this same callback, they would all compile as a single one, randomly selected from that list.

Any advice, ideas?

Comment: What about collecting your overrides, such that `FOO` has a list, and `BAR` has a list, and the `FOOandBAR` constructor concatenates them so when `onBeforeCompile` gets called, it uses the complete list?

Comment: I'm desperate and open to all suggestions, mind adding some code to this because i didn't quite understand it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm hesitant to say this is an answer. Also, my TypeScript is extremely rudimentary. But I mean something like this...

```
function copyHashes(input, output) {
    let key
    for (key in input) {
        output[key] = input[key]
    }
}

class foo {
    shaderStuff = {}
    constructor(params) {
        copyHashes({
            beginnormal_vertex: "",
            defaultnormal_vertex: "",
            normalmap_pars_fragment: ""
        },
            this.shaderStuff)

        this.onBeforeCompile = ()=>{
            // perform the replacement using this.shaderStuff
        }
    }
}

class bar extends foo {
    constructor(params) {
        super(params)
        copyHashes({
            somethingelse_vertex: "",
            other_pars_fragment: ""
        },
            this.shaderStuff)

        // you assigned onBeforeCompile during the constructor
        // so it wasn't inherited
        this.onBeforeCompile = ()=>{
            // perform the replacement using this.shaderStuff
            // in this case, this.shaderStuff contains the FULL
            // COMBINED list from both foo AND bar
        }
    }
}
```

What's happening is each class is appending their own overrides into `shaderStuff`. The way I have it written, any extending class will overwrite an existing override with their own.

If that doesn't make sense, or I'm misunderstanding the question, let me know.

Comment: Not sure if it makes sense, without the `onBeforeCompile` in there i'm not sure how it would get cached and if it would work at all.

Comment: Ahh but i think iget this with the static params, i'd only be doing it in the base class, others would be adding to it?

Comment: @pailhead `shaderStuff` gets inherited from `foo` into `bar`. `onBeforeCompile` is a function that gets called during the `render` process. So when it hits that for a `bar` object, the `shaderStuff` contains both sets of overrides.

Comment: Ok the body of the onBeforeCompile I think is crucial. If it’s the same exact body, I think it may not work

Comment: I’m afraid though that this idea is the only one that makes sense but in which case it can only work by overloading ShaderChunk and controlling it with defines

Comment: There is no inhreitance or chain-calling being applied to `onBeforeCompile`. This means the instance in `bar` is 100% separate and unique from the instance in `foo`. When `bar.onBeforeCompile()` is called, it will only run the definition from `bar`. If you write your replacer to be generic enough, it should be able to take ANY list from `shaderStuff` as its input.

Comment: I don’t think that’s the problem, the body of the function can’t be generic.

Comment: I’ll try to make a fiddle to illustrate the problem.